# Is an update of Google Play Services Neccessary for GCM

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I integrated in my App GCM as additional Feature. I included the newest Google Play Services SDK into my App.

As described into the GCM HowTo: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

I checked the persistence of the Play Services SDK with the Method `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`, what sometimes returns `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED`.

When an Update is available, does that mean that I can use GCM?
Because I don't care the Update, if the GCM Service is working, then I'm using that also if the user decides to don't update the Play Services (sometimes the users are at the previous Version, where it should work).

So is it possible (suggested) to register for GCM, also when the result is `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` ?

Comment: I might be wrong but I thought you only get the `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` when your app has a newer version than the user currently has on their device

Comment: Ok, trough the SDK Manager I always get the newest Version of the Play Services SDK. Where can I download older Versions and which one should I use? Is GCM always included?

Comment: you cannot download older versions, plus its always best to have the latest for any bug fixes there may be

Comment: Fact is that probably most of the users will ignore this update alert. So if a user has only one previous Build, then he should be able to get Push notifications...

Comment: then they cannot use your app, plus your app is not the only app that is going to be looking for the latest update at some point so they dont necessarily have to update through your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that it is, Google want that.

They don't provide us older SDK's for download, so we should use the newest one.

So users have to update that library to use all features of a specific App.